# Javascript Regex: count unescaped quotes in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a regex in Javascript for a seemingly simple problem, but I have been beating my head against the wall all morning about it. I'm trying to count the quotation symbols that occur in a string with string.match. The catch is that escaped quotation symbols should not be counted, but quotations which are preceded by an escaped backslash should be again.

As side information, I'm just trying to see if all strings present in the line are properly closed, and I'm reasoning there should be an equal number of quotes present in the line if this is the case.

A few examples:

```
'"I am string 1" "I am string 2"'
```

should obviously count 4 quotes

```
'"I am \"string 1\"" "I am string 2"'
```

should still count 4 quotes as the ones escaped inside string 1 should be skipped.

```
'"I am string 1\\" "I am string 2"'
```

should count 4 quotes, since the \ in front of the 2nd " is escaped by the \ before it.

I have found a regexp which does the job in ruby (and is formatted in pcre), but it uses constructs which do not exist in Javascript, such as negative lookbehinds `(?>!` and resetting the starting point of the match `\K`

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K"
```

I've tried to translate it to a Javascript regex, but with no avail.

I reckoned something like

```
(?:\\(?="))|(")
```

(match either a slash followed by a " or a slash on its own)
should do the trick, but it doesn't work and doesn't even account for the \" problem. Can anyone give me a lead? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a small parser to deal with this task as there is no `\G` operator that could anchor the subsequent matches to the end of the  previous successful match.

```js
var s = "\"some text\" with 5 unescaped double quotes... \\\"extras\" \\some \\\"string \\\" right\" here \"";

var res = 0;
var in_entity = false;
for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  if ((s[i] === '\\' && !in_entity) || in_entity) { // reverse the flag 
     in_entity = !in_entity;
  } else if (s[i] === '"'  && !in_entity) { // an unescaped "
      res += 1;
  }
}
console.log(s,": ", res);
```

Comment: Thanks! This appears to do the job. It just strikes me there is no way to solve this problem with a single regexp in Javascript. It seems so elementary.

Comment: It is not elementary for a regex in JS. In .NET, you could use a regex like [`^(?:[^"\\]|(")|\\.)*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a%5b%5e%22%5c%5c%5d%7c(%22)%7c%5c%5c.)*%24&i=%22text+%5c%22more%5c%22+text%22+and+no+more+%22escaped%22+quotes) and count the number of Group 1 captures. Same can be done with Python PyPi regex, and with specific build of the Boost regex library (that support capture collections).

Comment: Yes, I just have. This seems to the only possible option indeed in Javascript. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to grab the matches and count the length of resulting array:

```js
var arr=['"I am string 1" "I am string 2"',
         '"I am \\"string 1\\"" "I am string 2"',
         '"I am string 1\\\\" "I am string 2"'
        ];

for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   console.log(arr[i].match(/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/g).length * 2)
}
```

`/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/` will match quoted string consuming all the escaped characters inside.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJ6wK2/1)

**Output:**

```
4
4
4
```

Comment: This will fail if the input has an escaped `"` first. The truth is that you cannot solve the problem with a regex in JS. Write a small parser instead.

Comment: Yes this regex is only for input with balanced quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic solution is to first strip off any escaped quotes then re-escape the entire string.

```
val = '"I am \"string 1\"" "I am string 2"';
val = val.replace(/\"/gm, '"');
val = val.replace(/(["])/gm,'\$1');
```

Result will be:

```
'\"I am \"string 1\"\" \"I am string 2\"'
```